# C++ method pointer call yields undefined symbol error?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, c++builder-xe2

I would like to have a class that has a method pointer that points to one of two possible methods of the same class. I use Embarcadero XE2 bcc32 for this.

When I try the following, I get the Error `E2451 Undefined symbol findPosition`:

```
class A{
    public:
        double (A::*findPosition)(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh); //method pointer
        double mean(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){return 0;};               //case 1
        double median(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){return 0;};             //case 2
        A(){findPosition=&(A::mean);}                               //constructor set pointer to case 1
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vals(5,1);   // 1 1 1 1 1, example input

    A obj;
    obj.findPosition=&(A::median);   //set method pointer to case 2
    (obj.*findPosition)(vals,0);     //ERROR: E2451 Undefined symbol 'findPosition'

    system("pause");
}
```

Is `(obj.*findPosition)(vals,0)` not the correct version of a method-pointer call? Should I use `boost:bind` perhaps? Or is this generally a bad idea and I should stick to something like

```
class A{
    public:
        int flag;
        double findPosition(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){
            if(flag==0)return mean(arr,tresh);
            else if(flag==1)return median(arr,tresh);
        };
        double mean(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){return 0;};               //case 1
        double median(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){return 0;};             //case 2
        A(){flag=0;}                               //constructor set use to case 1
};
```

Comment: There is no variable `findPosition` in the scope of `main`. It's a member of `obj`. To call it, you would need to use `(obj.*obj.findPosition)(vals, 0);`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux wow, thanks for the quick and correct reply! `(obj.*obj.findPosition)` looks pretty ugly though... is there a way to avoid the `*obj.` part by changing something in the declaration?

Comment: Perhaps (*(obj.findPosition))(vals,0) ?

Comment: At the risk of missing a good reason why you are doing this, why not create an enum `enum CentralityMethod { Mean, Median, ... }` within A, a method `A::setCentralityMethod(CentralityMethod m)`, and have a regular member function `findPosition` that switches on the `CentralityMethod`?

Comment: Perhaps you can define a method like `double call(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh) { return (this->*findPosition)(std::move(arr), tresh); }`. Consider using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), if it's appropriate for you. Also consider making your methods `const` and using `const` references for to pass your value vectors around.

Comment: @GoldenSpecOps Thanks for the comment, but your suggestion yields `illegal use of member pointer`

Comment: @jwimberley Thanks for the comment! So, basically the second `Class A` I proposed, but with an enum? Well, it works, too, but I need the flag, define the switch function and keep updating it when new functions are added... But basically I was just wondering, if such things are realized nowadays by a "elegant" method pointer or by such a switch function. ^^

Comment: @Julian Essentially my enum method is just a more verbose version of your second `class A`. However, it keeps one benefit of your first version -- there is an obvious semantic meaning to `obj.findPosition=&(A::median)` and `obj.setCentralityMethod(A::CentralityMethod::Median)` that is lacking for `obj.setFlag(0)`. As always there is a tradeoff between elegance, readability, and maintainability. I personally don't think using a member function is modern or elegant; I recognize that the `enum` would require extra work when new methods are added, but seems like a small penalty.

Comment: Typo in my last comment -- should be "using a member function pointer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` and `->*` operators are defined as follows:

```
expression .* expression
expression ->* expression
```

Where the right-hand expression must evaluate to a pointer that is pointing to a member within the object specified by the left-hand expression.

The code fails to compile because you are trying to pass in a non-existent local variable for the right-hand expression.  That missing variable is what the compiler is complaining about.

You need something more like this instead:

```
(obj.*obj.findPosition)(vals,0);
```

Or, more clearer:

```
(obj.*(obj.findPosition))(vals,0);
```

Or, more verbose:

```
double (A::*fp)(std::vector<int>, int) = obj.findPosition;
(obj.*fp)(vals,0);
```

That being said, if you are not worried about portability to other compilers, you can use BCC's `__closure` extension instead:

```
class A{
    public:
        double (__closure *findPosition)(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh); //method pointer
        double mean(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){return 0;};               //case 1
        double median(std::vector<int> arr, int tresh){return 0;};             //case 2
        A(){findPosition=&mean;}                               //constructor set pointer to case 1
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> vals(5,1);   // 1 1 1 1 1, example input

    A obj;
    obj.findPosition=&(obj.median);   //set method pointer to case 2
    obj.findPosition(vals,0);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's very detailed and the `__closure` even helps with readability! However, I still wonder, if this is actually the right way of doing this instead of writing a method that switches between the methods based on a flag... that would seem more intuitive and should not hinder portability...

Comment: @Julian there is nothing wrong with using pointers to member methods. It is part of the language. You just have to use it correctly.